# Building a game GUI in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm in the process of building a GUI in java for a virtual pet game I'm working on, my main problem thus far is establishing the best way to get the result I want.

Basically I have a basic setup like this

JFrame (MainFrame)
Jpanel (MainPanel) This panel sits on the Jframe
I then add further panels to the main panel
menuPanel and gamePanel - I switch between panels using cardLayout

MenuPanel provides a basic menu to launch a game / load / help / exit (this is running fine).

GamePanel is where I'm running into issues.

I'm wanting to provide a screen to allow the player to input data (petName, Type etc) I was thinking of doing this as a panel and then switching to the gamePanel where the actual game will be played, but I don't know if this is the best way as I also want them to be able to check if the details are correct, if not allow them to reenter them.

The other problem I have is I want a setup like this

Area for pet (background, pet animations)
below this buttons which remain static.

```
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
v                   v
v                   v
v    Pet Area       v
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
v                   v
v    buttons        v
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
```

Ive tried to add two panels onto gamePanel - graphicPanel and buttonPanel, but netbeans has issues with panel hierarchy.

If someone has done a project similar and can give me some pointers to coding this better would be appreciated. It will work this way, but it seems messy and inefficient.

Comment: `CardLayout` is good start.  You might consider creating a semi transparent panel which you can overlay on the `GamePane` when you want the user to enter data, pausing the game under it, if possible.  This would require that the `GamePane` itself had it's own layout, like `OverlayLayout` or even a `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The other problem I have is I want a setup like this

I would do something like this:

```
public class gamePanel extends JPanel{
    private ButtonsPanel buttonsPanel;
    private GraphicsPanel graphicsPanel;

    public gamePanel(){
        super();
        this._initGUI();
    }
    private void _initGUI(){
        this.buttonsPanel = new ButtonsPanel();
        this.graphicsPanel = new GraphicsPanel();

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(graphicsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void run(){
        graphicsPanel.run();
    }
}

public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel(){

    public void run(){
        // this method could be called from the game loop.

        // ....
        // ....

        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        // here paint all graphics
    }
}

public class ButtonsPanel extends JPanel{
    public ButtonsPanel(){
        super();
        this._initGUI();
    }

    private void _initGUI(){
        // here add all the buttons you want..
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is the best way, but it works fine

Comment: Thank you, I assume I'm creating ButtonsPanel and GraphicsPanel in their own classes?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wanting to provide a screen to allow the player to input data (petName, Type etc)

That would probably be a model JDialog, instead of a panel on your main frame. Then you can redisplay the dialog and change the data as required.

> The other problem I have is I want a setup like this...

Seems like a [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) with one panel in the "CENTER" and the other in the "PAGE_END".